# How to use Automator to save a PDF's Metadata to Variable

Tags: automator, pdf

Essentially I wanted to get the author or title and save it as a variable to use as a subject for an email I am generating through automator. This is what I am attempting to do now:

[image]

The variable seems to be empty regardless of what I am doing. I am a total noob at automator and didn't even realize this amazing tool exists until a few days ago.

Comment: Not every PDF has that metadata, particularly if it has been scrubbed prior to being placed on the net.

Comment: I manually added metadata to verify for 100% fact that its there. I am not sure how to tell automator that I want the title variable to equal the title of the metadata or if I am going about this completely wrong.

Comment: The PDF action just puts all the selected metadata into a tab-delimited string, so you will need to break out the desired pieces.

Comment: that's the thing I am trying to figure out how to do, my automator-fu is weak

Comment: How are you manually adding the metadata?  If you are using something like ExifTool, it might be easier to just use that.